# Tmux window name changes when creating a new pane

Tags: tmux

I have several problems with windows names and panes.

First if I have a window named "myWin" and I create a new pane, the name is changed into "bash" whereas I want it to remain "myWin".

Second, if I have a two windows, "foo" and "bar", and I do `join-pane -s bar`, my window is renamed "bash" too.

To finish, I'd like that after my `join-pane -s bar`, when I do a `break-pane`, my window previously named "bar" is re-created with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you struggling with the same question — for me the issue happens when I set `default-terminal` in `.tmux.conf` to anything except:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

Which is really weird because [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ) definitely specifies that is should be `tmux` or `tmux-256color` or something similar.

I've tried different options and sometimes window name won't be changed but then something else stops working (i.e. normal behavior of the up button <kbd>↑</kbd>).

Also I use macOS Terminal and in *Preferences > Profiles > Advanced* I have setting *Declare terminal as* `xterm-256color` which is certainly related.